# When using TWRP, attempts to install ROM return error this package is for X; this is a ""

Tags: twrp, tablet, nvidia-shield

I have an old NVidia Shield Tablet (AFAIK, the "original" one, not K1 rebrand, not TV one) that I decided to dug out and find some use. Unlocked, loaded TWRP... but when I try to ADB Sideload a ROM from TWRP in Recovery Mode, even [this stock one I found](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-7-0-optimized-stock-shield-tablet-original-5-2-k1-5-2-14-08-17.3437791/), I get the following error:

```
This package is for "shieldtablet" devices; this is a "".
```

Considering trying to Google for `TWRP this is a ""` is absurdly impossible, I'm reaching out for help here.

I'm not an expert in Android stuff, but this seems like TWRP in Recovery Mode hasn't correctly detected what device my Shield Tablet is and I was also unsuccesfull in attempts to search for a solution that way.

I'm able to attempt ADB sideloads, I'm able to ADB push files into the tablet. But no ROM I found so far seem to get through because of TWRP seeing the device as `""`.

When I push a ROM like https://download.lineageos.org/foster_tab and try to install from within TWRP, I instead get an "Updater process ended with ERROR: 255"

I'm also unable to flash Lineage's own recovery image. When I attempt to `fastboot flash recovery lineage-18.1-20221212-recovery-foster_tab.img`, it returns the error `FAILED (remote: (InvalidSize))`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like the problem is TWRP being "too updated". Version [3.7](https://dl.twrp.me/shieldtablet/twrp-3.7.0_9-0-shieldtablet.img.html) wouldn't work, but following [this advice on XDA forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-7-0-optimized-stock-shield-tablet-original-5-2-k1-5-2-14-08-17.3437791/post-75746365), I installed [TWRP 3.1.1](https://dl.twrp.me/shieldtablet/twrp-3.1.1-1-shieldtablet.img.html) and could install Stock rom again.